# Sort a hash as keys in an array

Tags: perl

I have a hash

```
%value
g=>10
i=>55
k=>4
n=>100
```

I have an array

```
@letters = ('k','i','n','g')
```

please let me know how to sort my hash in the order of keys in the array.

Comment: how do you want the result, as a hash does not preserve order?

Comment: can I store into a different hash in the order of @letters?

Comment: Hashes do not preserve order, so if you need them ordered use an array of arrays or an Tie::IxHash from cpan

Comment: or keep the data in a hash (presumably there's some reason that was convenient) and keep the order you want to use them in an array of keys. but you already have that array in this case; just use it to get a slice of values (as in mpapec's answer) or loop over it: `for my $key (@letters) { my $value = $value{$key}; ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to print hash values in order in which they appear in `@letters` array then,

```
print join ",", @value{@letters};
```

Answer (score 4):

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Tie::IxHash;

my %hash = (
      g=>10,
      i=>55,
      k=>4,
      n=>100,
);

my %sorted_hash;
tie %sorted_hash, "Tie::IxHash";

my @array = ('k','i','n','g');
foreach(@array)
{
      if(defined($hash{$_}))
      {
            $sorted_hash{$_} = $hash{$_};
      }
}

print Dumper(%sorted_hash);
```

Prints:

```
$VAR1 = 'k';
$VAR2 = 4;
$VAR3 = 'i';
$VAR4 = 55;
$VAR5 = 'n';
$VAR6 = 100;
$VAR7 = 'g';
$VAR8 = 10;
```

Mention, that I used Tie::ixHash module. Otherwise, Perl won't keep array keys sorted.

> This Perl module implements Perl hashes that preserve the order in which the hash elements were added

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash](http://metacpan.org/pod/Tie%3a%3aIxHash)